# Nested CSS transitions issue when sliding content off/onto screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have a 2 column layout and the effect I'm trying to achieve is when a toggle button is clicked, the left (narrow) column animates off the screen. Then the remaining column expands to fill the remaining space.

Clicking the toggle again will essentially reverse the animation. With the content returning to it's original size and then the other column slides back to fill the space it left.

I have this working in essence but the transitions are causing a few problems. As I've added `transition-delay` onto the narrow column, this affects the child within it. Here's a CodePen:

https://codepen.io/moy/pen/zROvWN

Another issue I've noticed is the scrollbar appearing on the browser window even though there's more than enough space. I guess this is because it thinks the content in the narrow column has been squashed and is now really tall. Any ideas how I can avoid this and fix the issue I'm having?

### Edit

It might also be worth noting that the reason I have a wrapper div within the narrow column is the padding on the `.grid__item` elements caused a problem when setting transition on them. That's why I don't have a transition time on that column but it's applied to the `.filters` div within it.

Comment: you just want these both transitions to start at the same time? as soon as the left part will go to width 0 then right part should be 100%, with a smooth transition? right?

Answer (score 0):

I have Increased time from 0.4s to 1s, so that you can see the desired result eaisly,

If I misunderstood your requirment, fell free to discuss,
as I commented above,
all you need to do here is apply same time duration on both the elements, no delay required.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".filter-toggle").click(function(){
     $(".grid").toggleClass("hide-filters");
 });
});
```

```css
/* #MIXINS */
/* Body */
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* #GRID */
.grid {
  margin-left: -30px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid:before, .grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.grid:after {
  clear: both;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.one-half,
.two-quarters {
  width: 50%;
}

.one-third {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.two-thirds {
  width: 66.666%;
}

.one-quarter {
  width: 25%;
}

.three-quarters {
  width: 75%;
}

/* #THE PROBLEM */
.filter-controls {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.filter-controls .filter-toggle {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.filter-grid .filter-grid__filters {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.filter-grid .filters {
  -webkit-transition: all 10s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.filter-grid .filter-grid__content {
  -webkit-transition: width .40s;
  transition: width 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
          transition-delay: 0;
}

.hide-filters .filter-grid__filters {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.hide-filters .filter-grid__content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="filter-controls">
    <span class="btn filter-toggle">Toggle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="grid filter-grid">

    <div class="grid__item one-quarter filter-grid__filters">

      <div class="filters">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="grid__item three-quarters filter-grid__content">

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you noticed that the question is more than 2 years old ? And the user that posted the question has not logged in the last 3 months

Comment: Hey @vals, I really didn't see that, It just popped up in top question on the homepage and I answered it.